# Сохранение сразу нескольких сущностей в Spring Data

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

Допустим у меня есть сущности в СУБД `User` и `UserDetail` и все связи настроены правильно. Они связаны с друг другому один-к-одному через поле с одинаковым названием `user_id`. В `User` - это первичный ключ, а в `UserDetail` - это первичный и внешний ключ.

Как правильно сохранять такие объекты целиком ? Например, ко мне приходит новый объект `User` с уже готовым `UserDetail`. Если сделать репозиторий `UserRepository` и наследовать его от `CrudRepository`, а потом вызвать метод `save`, то hibenate ругнется, что такого `UserDetail` еще нет. Так как вставки проходят не сразу, я не могу создать объект `UserDetail`. Чтобы я не делал, `hibernate` не знает про сохраненному в СУБД `User`.

Comment: Указаны ли аннотации "Вставлять/Удалять каскадно"?

Comment: Как образец: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157853/hibernate-how-use-cascade-in-annotation

Comment: Добавил аннотации `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)`. Ничего не изменилось.

Comment: То есть, `@Cascade(PERSIST)`

Comment: попробуйте CascadeType.ALL и в обоих направлениях (и у класса User и у класса UserDetail). Если уже и это не поможет, тогда действительно надо разбираться почему.

Comment: Хотя, для вставки User-объекта с заполненным UserDetail, достаточно указать CascadeType только у User-модели.

Comment: @test123 а это может быть как-то связано как-то с особенностями `Oracle bd` ?

Comment: Очень сильно сомневаюсь. Хибер должен решать такие вопросы независимо от драйвера и типа базы.

Comment: Ещё один момент. Чтобы Хибер знал что сущность вы только что создали, и её ещё нет в базе, у вашей сущности значение в качестве первичного ключа обязан быть null.

Comment: Ничего не изменилось с `ALL`. По сути у меня ошибка по `constraint`. `UserDetails` пытается сохраниться, но не может т.к. не прошел коммит по сохранению `User`. У `Oracle` есть особенность, что надо делать коммит после каждой вставки... Я подозреваю, что возможно проблема в этом.

Comment: Про `null` я знаю.

Comment: Тогда прошу простить, с ораклом я не сталкивался, вряд ли смогу помочь :(